Is there any unsupervised online learning rule for classical neural networks?
In spike-based neural networks, there is a learning rule called STDP (Spike-Timing-Dependent Plasticity).
It's a completely unsupervised learning rule that works continuously when data is fed into the network.
I've been trying to find learning rules that work like STDP, but can be applied to a numerical-based network with multiple layers, and complex connections (e.g., multi-layer perceptron).
I found some interesting techniques such as: Principal Component Analysis, Kohonen's Self-Organizing Map, Competitive Learning, Oja's Rule, and the Hebbian rule.
But none of these can be applied to a deeper neural network with multiple layers and more complex connections.
I'm looking for a learning rule that works unsupervised and online, similar to STDP, but that can be applied to traditional neural networks.

Have you considered auto encoders?

What kind of auto encoders do you mean? Because the simple idea of auto encoders is to learn using supervised backpropagation to convert the input information to a smaller input space and then decode it back as best as possible.

Autoencoding is a form of unsupervised machine learning. So it's unclear what you're looking for. Unsupervised and online is extremely broad is very broad.
